# Temp folder in MAC for specific requirement

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

My requirement is, for each user uses my application there will be set of files created for the user. I am looking for right folder in Mac (Similar to C:\Windows\Temp in windows)

Condition:

1. Folder should be accessible to all users.
2. Content should not be deleted after logoff.
3. Folder should not be GUID based like echo $TMPDIR. Path should be static irrespective of user.
4. Any logged in user should be able to create directory there (even non admin
   users).

   If you know specific directory, please let me know how do we get this path programetically in objective C.

Comment: Can it be erased at startup ?

Comment: No. These files should be retained unless user deleted them through application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `NSApplicationSupportDirectory` or `NSCachesDirectory`

```
NSString *downloadPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyApp"];
```

Comment: In both of NSApplicationSupportDirectory or NSCachesDirectory, UserName is added to the path. Not generic path.

Comment: Then you can try NSSystemDomainMask instead of NSUserDomainMask. But I don't think the guest user's will have the access for the path.

Comment: Folder is /System/Library/Cache. This is restricted folder.Even for admin user, it will ask for Password.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the "Shared" folder which is located in `/Users`.

"The Shared folder is located in the Users folder on your hard disk, with your home folder and the home folders of any other people who have accounts on your Mac. You can use the Shared folder to share files with other users on your Mac. The Shared folder is set up so that all users on your Mac can open files in the folder and copy files to it."

This is not a "temporary" folder, whose content will eventually be deleted by the system!

See also: [OS X Mavericks: What are the Shared and Public folders?](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH13957)

Unfortunately, there is no corresponding `NSSearchPathDirectory` constant which would return the path via `NSFileManager`s method `URLsForDirectory:inDomains:`.

See also: [URLsForDirectory:inDomains:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsfilemanager_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-SW102)

Comment: Problem with Shared folder is that, If the folder is created by X user, Y user can't make any change like create sub folder etc., unless  full permission is given root/base folder. If this is the requirement, then I could go for creating folder in /Applications itself.What I want is- is there any folder in Mac which can be used by any user and modify other users content. For example - C:\WIndows\Temp - Any one can modify files of other users. I understand, this behaviour in Mac is for security reason. And it makes sense. Anyways, I will use /Applications folder itself for now.

Comment: @RamaprasadUpadhyaya IMO, the "Shared" folder will be created by the system, when there are more than one users. And by the way, you can set virtually any access rules, utilizing ACL or Unix permissions.

Comment: Currently I am doing that (providing permission to the folder using command-chmod) in /Applications folder. I wanted to avoid providing folder permissions like this.Anyways, I will go with /Applications folder storage.

Comment: @RamaprasadUpadhyaya The /Applications folder is definitely not the right one. It requires admin access. The only folder that can be accessed from multiple users with user rights is /Shared.